# Ionic - Angular with Capacitor on Android : All app updates must use Billing Library version 4 or newer. in-app-purchase-2

Tags: ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, capacitor, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

**Version used:** "@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-purchase-2": "^5.46.0",

**Actions on Webstorm (ionic project) :**

```
ionic build
npx cap sync
npx cap open android
```

**Actions on Android Studio:**

- Generate a signed bundle

**Actions on google play console:**

- Create new release with the signed bundle

**Warning on google play** :
We've detected that this app is using an old version of Google Play Billing. By November 1, 2022, all app updates must use Billing Library version 4 or newer. Update to Billing Library 4 before this date.

**What I tried without success:**

- Add these two lines in the build.graddle:app and in capacitor.build.graddle and in the capacitor-cordova-android-plugins/build.graddle:

  ```
    dependencies {
        ....
        implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0"
    }
  ```

**What I want:**
How do I update the PlayBillingLibrary from ionic and have it be taken into account with Capacitor when i sync my app on android (npx cap sync) ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `cordova-plugin-purchase` to version `11.0.0` or higher (see [`RELEASE_NOTES.md`](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#upgrade-to-google-play-billing-library-v40)).

Comment: You made my day thanks ! 

On the release not you sent, we can see version 12.0.0 but on the npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-purchase) the last version is 11.0.0 at this day.
Do you know how i can upgrade to Play Billing Library V5 ?

Comment: In this case, v12 is not yet officially released. You need to wait for the maintainer to release it or fork the project and release it yourself.